# Best Practice for an Odd Situation

Tags: c++, windows, logging, asynchronous, server

I am trying to implement asynchronous logging for a Windows server that is running a resource-intensive service; I don't want it waiting on any responses (which could be delayed) from my SQL db. I am coding in C++.

The easiest method I've identified is simply spawning a new process in Windows. The process is just a dumb console application which takes in parameters on start-up and spits the data to my database. Basically, this application opens, executes, and then closes rather rapidly. I already have this working and it was quite simple to implement. The problem is, I feel like an idiot having made it. There must be a better way. Won't there be a lot of overhead for this? On my server, I could have up to 20 "ports" listening for requests - so in theory I could have 20 instances of my little logging application bouncing around, which seems bad to me. I don't know if the Windows OS is optimized for this sort of thing or if it's a good idea.

But I've thought through my options and they don't seem pretty? I was thinking of creating a logging service which listens for requests. I could, instead of spawning a new process, use some kind of asynchronous pipe to send data to my logging service? Does that sound like a better approach? I'm concerned about the effort involved though; I've never done something like this before so I don't know if it's a good idea. In general, I should probably tone down the noise to my DB and try to chunk logging insert requests, though that may be a little overkill (I'm not sure how "noisy" my logging will end up being just yet).

I've not brainstormed any better ideas, either. I would like some opinions or better direction, if anyone's feeling generous. Am I just worrying about nothing?

Comment: Have you considered using threads, rather than separate processes?

Comment: It's a little complicated, Re-reading my post I didn't do a good job of explaining the situation. Each port cannot spawn a thread because an end user is waiting for the service's response. Each port is basically an instance and the port must "close" to allow new requests to be accepted. If the process's function call is still waiting on a log-thread to complete, the code is essentially still synchronized.

Comment: No reason to wait for the thread to complete. You can either start and forget threads like you do with your processes (not recommended as they might pile up in memory, similar to your processes), or add the log message to a queue that another thread or thread pool is processing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you link to an example implementation? If a process spawns a child thread, you can't kill/"close"/release that process until all its child threads are dead. I don't know of any "fire and forget" kinda of threading mechanism in c++. If a child thread is still alive, the "wait for process" call will still wait. You're creating zombie threads, otherwise, which is a horrible idea? That's why my process is currently spawning a separate program all together to log, to get around the "wait until all child threads are dead" problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that your workers were separate processes that start, do their work and finish. I was picturing that they were either long running workers in a pool or just threads themselves. In that case, you could look at using something like zeromq (http://zeromq.org/) to pass asynchronous messages to a logging listener.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! And yeah, my question wasn't very explicit.